# What to do if exec() fails?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc, fork

Let's suppose we have a code doing something like this:

```
int pipes[2];
pipe(pipes);
pid_t p = fork();
if(0 == p)
{
   dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
   execv("/path/to/my/program", NULL);
   ...
}
else
{
//... parent process stuff
}
```

As you can see, it's creating a pipe, forking and using the pipe to read the child's output (I can't use `popen` here, because I also need the PID of the child process for other purposes).

Question is, what should happen if in the above code, `execv` fails? Should I call exit() or abort()? As far as I know, those functions close the open file descriptors. Since `fork`-ed process inherits the parent's file descriptors, does it mean that the file descriptors used by the parent process will become unusable?

**UPD**

I want to emphasize that the question is not about the executable loaded by exec() failing, but exec itself, e.g. in case the file referred by the first argument is not found or is not executable.

Comment: If you don't want a confusing control flow, I would recommend exit() with a known exit code on failed exec.

Comment: Hey guys, but what if `exit()` fails as well?

Comment: I don't think this should be a concern - any funny stuff going on in `atexit` functions will result in abnormal termination in the worst case, otherwise we have no control over it (exit never returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `exit(int)` since the (low byte) of the argument can be read by the parent process using `waitpid()`. This lets you handle the error appropriately in the parent process. Depending on what your program does you may want to use `_exit` instead of `exit`. The difference is that `_exit` will not run functions registered with `atexit` nor will it flush stdio streams.

Answer (score 0):

There are about a dozen reasons `execv()` can fail and you might want to handle each differently.

The child failing is not going to affect the parent's file descriptors.  They are, in effect, reference counted.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `_exit()`. It does everything `exit()` does, but it avoids invoking any registered `atexit()` functions. Calling `_exit()` means that the parent will be able to get your failed child's exit status, and take any necessary steps.